# Does a table cell have a containing block?

Tags: html, css

According to http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html, some elements can have a "containing block". Does a table cell `td` have a containing block, like `tr`?

e.g.

```
<div>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>hi</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The section linked to above says:

> 2. For other elements, if the element's position is 'relative' or 'static', the containing block is formed by the content edge of the nearest block container ancestor box.

Now, a table-row box is not a block container box because it only contains table-cell boxes, which are not block-level boxes. Neither is a table a block container box because it can only contain other types of boxes, none of which are block-level (e.g. row groups).

Looking at the section on [tables](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/tables.html), the only references to a containing block in that section refer to the containing block of a table, not a table-cell.

Based on this, it's probably safe to assume that the containing block of a table-cell box or any other internal table box is the same as the containing block of the table in which it resides (which, in your example, is the `div`). A more conservative reader might prefer to assume that the containing block of any internal table box is undefined.