# mix-blend-mode with table cell that have position sticky

Tags: html, css

I have very weird behavior that happens in both Google Chrome and Firefox.

I have a table with a gradient background that creates zebra stripes. The cells have a white background and I use mix blend mode to hide the cells that are sticky so only one sticky cell that is visible.

The problem is that when the table cell is sticky, blend mode doesn't work properly and you see multiple cells at once. But if I put div inside the cell and make the div sticky it magically works. Any idea why?

The difference between the table is this:

```css
.table-A .level-2 [rowspan] div,
.table-B .level-0 div,
.table-B td[rowspan] {
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
}
```

And both tables have:

```css
.level-2 [rowspan] {
    background: white;
    mix-blend-mode: multiply;
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

You can see the issue in this [CodePen demo](https://codepen.io/jcubic/pen/NWbXoVB?editors=1100)

and in this screen:

[image]

My question is why this is happening why cells work differently than div inside. As you can see from the demo I already know how to solve the issue I only want to know why it's behaving like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refer to the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position):

> A **stickily positioned element** is an element whose computed `position` value is `sticky`. It's treated as relatively positioned until its containing block crosses a specified threshold (such as setting `top` to value other than auto) within its flow root (or the container it scrolls within), at which point it is treated as "stuck" until meeting the opposite edge of its containing block.

So your problem is not caused by `td` or `div` itself. It's because of their [containing block](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Containing_block):

> If the position property is `static`, `relative`, or `sticky`, the containing block is formed by the edge of the content box of the nearest ancestor element that is either **a block container** (such as an inline-block, block, or list-item element) or **establishes a formatting context** (such as a table container, flex container, grid container, or the block container itself).

For sticky with the `div` inside `td`, it's clear that the containing block is its parent `td`(because `td` establishes a [formatting context](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flow_Layout/Intro_to_formatting_contexts#creating_a_new_block_formatting_context)) so each `div` have its own containing block and will not be stacked.

For sticky with `td`, I haven't found any official document about containing block of `td`, only found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25590816/does-a-table-cell-have-a-containing-block), so I'm not sure it's a `tbody`, `table` or the div that wrap the table. The only thing can be sure is all the `td` sharing the same containing block, that's why it's stacked.

Comment: Does it mean that `position: sticky` on the table cell is unspecified? It looks like both Chrome and Firefox implemented it exactly the same.

Comment: It's just unclear, not unspecified because the docs give us infomations to guess what's the containing block. In this case it should be the div wrap the table because it has `overflow-y: auto` but the `td` is just "stuck" inside the table so I think I've missed something.